# MySQL Where clause values 0 and 1 not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, enums

### The situation

In table I have columns configurated as `ENUM('0','1')`. I have select query build with PDO like this example

```
$value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : (isset($_GET["value"]) ? $_GET["value"] : null);

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column = :value");
$sql->bindValue(':value', $_POST['value']); // post contains 0 or 1
$sql->execute();
```

---

### The problem

When printing the results, value 1 is working normally. But when using value 0, all rows are showing including rows with value 1.

Following query is working normally when trying it in HeidiSQL, but it's not with PHP. What's wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column = '0'
```

I noticed that PHP thinks `$_POST['value']` is unset when its value is zero. I'm using `isset()`

---

### Trying to solve the problem

- **No effect** either if using `$_GET['value']` and url like `index.php?value=0`
- Tried following, **not working**

  ```
  $sql->bindValue(':value', '0'); // post contains 0 or 1
  ```
- I changed column type to `TINYINT(1)` - **no effect.** When looking for zero, all are showing.
- Set PDO `bindValue()` `$data_type` to `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`, **not working**

Comment: it should work may be problem is in $_POST value

Comment: your PHP version is targeting a table named 'tablename', try putting 'customers_view' there instead.
or is this just a copy-paste-error?

Comment: @Carsten, that was just a copy-paste-error.. I tried to use `tablename` and `column` here in Stackoverflow. Thanks for pointing it - edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$value = empty($_POST['value']) ? '0' : '1' ;

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column = :value");
$sql->bindValue(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR); // post contains 0 or 1
$sql->execute();
```

Good luck!

Comment: No effect. And my code doesn't work either when using `$_GET['value']` and url like `index.php?value=0`

Comment: Replace $value with '0', so: _$sql->bindValue(':value', '0', PDO::PARAM_STR);_ See if it works like that, also check my latest edits to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.

An enumeration value must be a quoted string literal; it may not be an expression, even one that evaluates to a string value.

> The index value of the empty string error value is 0. This means that
>   you can use the following SELECT statement to find rows into which
>   invalid ENUM values were assigned:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE enum_col=0;
```

So use single quote to consider the zero(0) as string.